# Laravel 5.2 Validation not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have following forms

```
{{ Form::text("theme[header_color]", '', []) }}
{{ Form::text("theme[bg_color]", '', []) }}
{{ Form::text("theme[text_color]", '', []) }}
```

I added following rules in request method.

```
theme[text_color]="required",
theme[bg_color]="required",
theme[text_color]="required"
```

I enter value in all field but still getting required validation error.

Please help have a look and help us.

THanks

Comment: Laravel uses the dot notation to access array members. Try using `theme.text_colour` etc instead in the validation. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input (3rd example)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code does this help

```
        $rules = array(
            'theme.text_color' => 'required',
            'theme.bg_color' => 'required',
            'theme.header_color' => 'required',
        );
        $messages = [
            'theme.text_color.required' => 'Please add Text Color.',
            'theme.bg_color.required' => 'Please add Text Color.',
            'theme.header_color.required' => 'Please add Header Color.',
          ];
```

Comment: i tried but now validation not fired even if value is empty.